# Premier Pro CC 2015 Lag Issues!

Tags: video, premiere, editing

So updated to the new release this week and after spending a few days getting the damn thing to work with my previous projects and having to uninstall and reinstall my graphics card and enable CUDA the new Premier is simply unusable! Ever ajustment takes at least 2-3 seconds to appear in the monitor, you can't preview the timeline without having to render in/out first and the render times have gone from 3-4 minutes to about 4-5 hours!!

CC 2014 worked absolutely fine. On the same projects/footage. My rig is pretty up to date; Intel i7, 16gb Ram, NVidia GeForce 860 GPU.

Is anyone else having issues? I'd roll back to the earlier version but I'd lose all this weeks work (as I've been making use of the great lumetri colour ajustments).

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Okay, so I started a new project and step by step worked out where it was gong wrong. Everything was fine until I started using a 'creative look'. After that, death.

Comment: yes I am having the same issue!